# How can I access the name of the current route in meteor when using meteor-router?

Tags: meteor

I'm building an app using [meteor](http://meteor.com/) and [meteor router](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router), and I would like to make a template helper for checking if the route is a specific one (`{{#ifRouteIs login}}{{/ifRouteIs}}`).

Comment: Note that as of 2015, meteor-router has been deprecated in favour of iron-router, and other routers exist too (react-router, flow-router).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue. Building on your answer, I found a working solution. It needs to go in the client side of Meteor.

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifRouteIs', function (routeName, options) { 
  if (Meteor.Router.page() === routeName) {
    return options.fn(this);
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

Answer (score 4):

According to meteor-router's [README](https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router/blob/master/README.md), you can get the current page with `Meteor.Router.page()`, so the helper might look like this:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifRouteIs', function (routeName) {
  return Meteor.Router.page() === routeName;
});
```